# Why do I get a Swift error with nested associated types

Tags: swift, generics

I would like to create a couple protocols to have a more type-safe friendly `Notification` interface.

The idea is to have a single type which from it, can be retrieved the notifications name, user info type (which will be the only entry of the dict), and a delegate for simplifying the observed response with the user info as a parameter.

Here are two protocols to help with building this interface.

```
protocol StructuredNotificationIdentifier {
    associatedtype Delegate: StructuredNotificationUserInfoType
    static var notification: Notification.Name { get }
}

protocol StructuredNotificationUserInfoType {
    associatedtype UserInfoType
}
```

Here is an implementation of a notification with its name, user info type, and protocol.

```
protocol SomethingDidHappenDelegate: StructuredNotificationUserInfoType where UserInfoType == String {
    func somethingDidHappen(_ value: UserInfoType)
}

enum SomethingDidHappenNotification: StructuredNotificationIdentifier {
    typealias Delegate = SomethingDidHappenDelegate
    static var notification: Notification.Name { Notification.Name("SomethingDidHappenNotification") }
}
```

And here is one more example of how the interface becomes simplified.

```
extension NotificationCenter {
    func post<T: StructuredNotificationIdentifier>(identifier: T, userInfo: T.Delegate.UserInfoType) {
        post(name: type(of: identifier).notification, object: nil, userInfo: ["info": userInfo])
    }
}
```

Now, my error happens on the `enum` declaration.

> Type 'SomethingDidHappenNotification' does not conform to protocol 'StructuredNotificationIdentifier'

The problem as I understand it is coming from the `StructuredNotificationIdentifier.Delegate` requiring conformance of `StructuredNotificationUserInfoType` which also needs a defined `associatedtype`. The part that I'm confused about is why this is not resolved with the `SomethingDidHappenDelegate` declaration?

I understand I can set the user info type in multiple places, however since this is a pattern I'll be using often, I wanted the least amount of redundant code needed for the setup.

Why am I getting this error and is there an elegant way to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Protocols don't conform to protocols](https://forums.swift.org/t/protocol-type-cannot-conform-because-only-concrete-types-can-conform-to-protocols/28524), so although it seems like

```
typealias Delegate = SomethingDidHappenDelegate
```

satisfies the `Delegate` associated type requirement of `StructuredNotificationIdentifier`, it doesn't, because `Delegate` must conform to `StructuredNotificationUserInfoType`. And `SomethingDidHappenDelegate`, being a protocol, does not conform to any protocols.

I tried to come up with a workaround, and this is what I've got:

```
protocol StructuredNotificationIdentifier {
    associatedtype Delegate
    associatedtype UserInfoType
    static var notification: Notification.Name { get }
}

protocol SomethingDidHappenDelegate {
    func somethingDidHappen(_ value: String)
}

enum SomethingDidHappenNotification: StructuredNotificationIdentifier {
    typealias Delegate = SomethingDidHappenDelegate
    typealias UserInfoType = String
    static var notification: Notification.Name { Notification.Name("SomethingDidHappenNotification") }
}

extension NotificationCenter {
    func post<T: StructuredNotificationIdentifier>(identifier: T, userInfo: T.UserInfoType) {
        post(name: type(of: identifier).notification, object: nil, userInfo: ["info": userInfo])
    }
}
```

I moved `UserInfoType` into `StructuredNotificationIdentifier` as well and deleted the constraint on `Delegate`, because I don't think it is possible to access `T.Delegate.UserInfoType` when `Delegate` is a protocol. The error message I got when I tried to do that was pretty clear:

> Associated type 'UserInfoType' can only be used with a concrete type or generic parameter base

Answer (score 1):

The following makes your code compilable

```
enum SomethingDidHappenNotification<D: SomethingDidHappenDelegate>: StructuredNotificationIdentifier {
    typealias Delegate = D
    static var notification: Notification.Name { Notification.Name("SomethingDidHappenNotification") }
}
```